# Symfony - Return svg markup without html or body tags

Tags: html, symfony, svg, response, markup

Good day community,

I have a little bit of a problem with a symfony controller right now.
I want to dynamically create a svg and display only the markup of the svg on my webpage.

Like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="40" height="40"><rect x="0" y="0" width="40" height="40" style="fill: #0000FF" /></svg>
```

But when I try to return my svg I always end up with the html and body tags in the response:

```
<!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?--><html><head></head><body><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="40" height="40"><rect x="0" y="0" width="40" height="40" style="fill: #0000FF"></rect></svg></body></html>
```

In my Controller I generate the svg via the following bundle: https://github.com/meyfa/php-svg

```
$image = new SVG(40,40);
        $doc = $image->getDocument();
        $square = new SVGRect(0, 0, 40,40);
        $square->setStyle('fill', '#0000FF');
        $doc->addChild($square);

        return new Response($image->toXMLString());
```

My aim is to only display the svg on the page so that I could use the generated image on another page like this:

```
<img src="https://mypage/mygeneratedsvg">
```

Anyone got any ideas or Input for me?

Answer (score 1):

right after posting the question I came up with the conclusion.
It is so simple ..

I had to define the Content-Type in the headers like this:

```
return new Response($image->toXMLString(), 200, ['Content-Type' => 'image/svg+xml']);
```